# Node not found: "AnimationPlayer" (relative to "/root/Background/Watering")

Tags: godot

Bro help me. I am trying to do it so that when I click the textured button an animation will play, instead it just crashes the game with the error,

the animation name Watering

the code:

```
extends TextureButton


func _on_pressed():
    print("Button pressed!")
    $AnimationPlayer.play("Watering/Watering")
```

Comment: Your code expects to be attached to a `TextureButton` that has an `AnimationPlayer` called `"AnimationPlayer"` as child... But it does not find it. Apparently the script is attached to a node called `Waterning`, and from it, Godot can't find a node called `"AnimationPlayer"`. And yes, I'm reiterating what you already know and what the error told you.